# PrimeNg OverlayPanel with custom template param

Tags: angular, primeng, ng-template

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible in any way to pass a custom parameter to the overlayPanel of PrimeNg.

It should look something like this: (notice the `let-item` param in the `ng-template`)

```
<p-overlayPanel #op>
    <ng-template pTemplate let-item>
        <div (click)="this.delete(item.id)">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I'm opening this panel from each list item in my UI, and I need a reference to the item that the panel was opened from.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure out the same scenario.  As long as you can reference `item`, I got it working by removing the `ng-template` element:

```
<p-overlayPanel #op>
    <div (click)="this.delete(item.id)">
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</p-overlayPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's how I resolved it either, but this isn't answering my question. I don't want to save a reference to the `item` variable myself...